# A basis with constant metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Let's consider a plane which coordinates are $x^1,x^2$. Then, consider the basis given by ${\partial \vec P/\partial x^i}$.
Accordingly to this choice of coordinates and basis there will be a metric tensor in every point $T(x^i)$.

Is it possible to find coordinates such that the basis $\partial \vec P/\partial x^i$  change from point to point but the metric tensor is constant,$T(x^i)=constant$?

For example, with cartesian coordinates the metric tensor is constant but the basis is also constant everywhere so it does't satisfy the requirement.